Confused about stresses in a small element in solid mechanics
So in the diagram of a stress tensor, the normal and shear stresses on opposite faces of the small cube are equal and opposite. This is justified by equilibrium.
On the other hand, in the differential equations of equilibrium (eg beams, shear flow, plate), small elements can have varying stresses on opposite faces.
Are we considering different sizes of infinitesimal elements?

In a way, yes, we are considering different sized of infinitesimal elements.  The stress tensor describes the state at a point in the fluid, while the force balance involves the traction vectors on the faces of an infinitesimal element, derived from the components of the stress tensor using the Cauchy stress relationship.


So in the diagram of a stress tensor, the normal and shear stresses on opposite faces of the small cube are equal and opposite. Justified by equilibrium.

This is not true. In static conditions, local equilibrium of a 3-dimensional system reads
$$\nabla \cdot \sigma \hspace{-4pt} \sigma + \mathbf{f} = \mathbf{0} \ ,$$
being $\sigma \hspace{-4pt} \sigma$ the stress tensor and $\mathbf{f}$ the volume force density.
The condition $$\mathbf{t}_{n,1} = \mathbf{t}_{n,2} \ ,$$
holds across a zero-tickness unloaded surface, i.e. a possible discontinuity, and it's the jump condition that it's possible to derive from integral form of the equilibrium equation for an elementary volume across that surface.
1-dimensional example: axial force in 1-dimensional elements. In order to make a simple example, let's take the axial force of a 1-dimensional element. Equilibrium equation along the axis reads
$$\frac{dN(x)}{dx} + f(x) = 0 \ ,$$
i.e. the axial internal action $N(x)$ is not constant if there is a load per unit length $f(x)$. If you want to see where this equation comes from, let's evaluate the equilibrium of the elementary chunk with length $\Delta x$ centered in $x$ of the 1-dimenisonal element; axial forces acting on this chunk are:

the internal actions made explicit by the fictitious cut of the element, $-N(x-\Delta x/2)$ at section $x-\Delta x/2$ and $N(x+\Delta x/2)$ at section $x+\Delta x/2$
the external force per unit length, $f(x)$.

Equilibrium reads
$$\begin{aligned}
0 & = -N(x-\Delta x/2) + N(x+\Delta x/2) + \int_{x-\Delta x/2}^{x+\Delta x/2} f(t) d t = \\
& = - N(x) + \frac{dN(x)}{dx} \frac{\Delta x}{2} + N(x) + \frac{dN(x)}{dx} \frac{\Delta x}{2} + f(x) \Delta x + o(\Delta x) = \\
& = \Delta x \left( N'(x) + f(x) \right) + o(\Delta x) \ .
\end{aligned}$$
The first order contribution as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0 $ gives you the desired local equilibrium condition $N'(x) + f(x) = 0$.
